# How well do Convolutional neural networks in other image domains?

Tags: neural-networks, pattern-recognition, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I was recently trying out caffe and learning about CNN. So far I have seen that the model used by Krizhevsky performs really well in natural images. However I wanted to know how these models or CNN based models would behave in domains such as biological images or medical images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they do. See the following links:

- http://people.idsia.ch/~juergen/nips2012.pdf
- http://blog.kaggle.com/2014/04/18/winning-the-galaxy-challenge-with-convnets/